# Disabling sorting in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Here is the code i am using

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.d-table').dataTable( {
      "responsive": true,
      "columnDefs": [ { "targets": 0,"searchable": false, 'bSortable': false } ]
    });   
  })
```

This code is disabled first column sorting but I want to disable Sorting completely  while i sort other columns.

Comment: An comment to my answer would be beneficial if it has solved your problem or not. If yes then you can accept it.

Comment: The only issue is `'bSortable'` should be `"bSortable"` make sure to keep your quote tags the same.

Comment: Also add `"order": [[1, "asc"]]` after your columnDefs so it well sort then next column by default.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling the particular column sorting you can specify column index for disabling as below

For first column :

```
"columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 0,
            "orderable": false
        } ]
```

If you want to disable the sorting completely in DataTable. There is property called **"bSort"** you can set it to **"false"** it will remove the sorting from whole table.

like below

```
 $('.d-table').dataTable( {
    "bSort": false
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/k1pm5ne0/

Comment: i want to disable sorting for first column only. this has disabled entire table